# Should I concern the close of controller in Marionette?

Tags: marionette

Let's use an example of a blog built by Marionett. The blog post is a sub app and hook the route `post/:id`. It also has a controller, inherited from `Marionette.Controller`. Quite normal.

Each hit to `post/:id` will create a new controller instance, managing the related model and views. The controller instance will trigger App.vents but won't listen on App.vents.

My question is, since there will be so many instances of the controller created when an user navigates around, should I concern the close of the instances when there are a `close()` method available in controller? Will there be memory leak if not closing them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a memory leak depending on what's inside your controllers. Also if you're controller is using listenTo to watch events on other models/objects you could get a build up of zombie events. Without seeing your code it would be hard to say for sure.

In general, I think why not just close the controllers? The way I do this (from BackboneRails tutorials) is to have the first view controller the renders (typically a layout) as the main view and then bind to the view's close event--when the view closes the controller will call close on itself. You can build this into your base controller so it happens automatically. This has worked pretty well for me...

Comment: Evan, you are right. Actually I've already done that as per Brian's tut but forgot it. Thanks for your answer. I recalled that and have more understanding.